# Deduction guide and specialization to find out if the template parameters were specified: not working

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class... T>
struct structure
{
    template <class... Args>
    constexpr structure(Args&&...) noexcept {
        std::cout << "structure<T...>" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class... T>
struct structure<void, T...>
{
    template <class... Args>
    constexpr structure(Args&&...) noexcept {
        std::cout << "structure<void, T...>" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <class... Args>
structure(Args&&...) -> structure<void, Args...>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    structure<int> s1(42);
    structure s2(42);
    return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
structure<T...>
structure<T...>
```

while I would have expected:

```
structure<T...>
structure<void, T...>
```

Why is the deduction guide failing in that context? Or at least not working as I would have expected.

Comment: tldr; gcc bug, clang does the right thing here